# axios get function with parameters in get method causing 404 errors when it is null or empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I written vue.js code with axios as follows, It is working fine but of branchid is null or empty it is returning 404 error always , how can write condition to this api call if my id existed then only it will return .

```js
@TrackFlight(FlightToken.getMylocationData)
getBranchData(bId) {
  return axios.get(`/api/v2/mybranch/${bId}`);
}
```

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Add an if check before the axios request and check if the id has a value.

As the axios is a promise based, you can use `Promise.reject`. if the id is invalid just return `Promise.reject` and catch this in your calling function in the catch block.

```
@TrackFlight(FlightToken.getMylocationData)
getBranchData(bId) {
  if (!bId) return Promise.reject("Invalid ID");
  return axios.get(`/api/v2/mybranch/${bId}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@TrackFlight(FlightToken.getMylocationData)
getBranchData(bId) {
  if (bId) {
    return axios.get(`/api/v2/mybranch/${bId}`);
  } else {
    console.log('bId is not Existed');
  }
}
```

404 is return usually caused by wrong path(url), missing params / value in params,
do check the console, usually the url is display back along with the error.

Answer (score 0):

Hi solved it by throwing the error : Here is my code

```
@TrackFlight(FlightToken.getMylocationData)
getBranchData(bId) {
  if (!bId) return throw new TypeError("Invalid Id");
  return axios.get(`/api/v2/mybranch/${bId}`);
```